# How come bisect doesn't find my intent?

Tags: python, threshold, bisect

I'm using bisect to find first occurence of datapoint > -6, but when I run my script it only finds the second (and last) occurence.

```
    import bisect

    kk = [-9, -6, -4, -6, -8, -8, -7, -7, -6, -6, -5]

    first = bisect.bisect(kk, -6)
    print(first)
```

This piece of code outputs "10" but should be "2". Can anyone tell me why?
I'm sorry in advance for a propably stupid question - I'm VERY new to Python!

Comment: `bisect` performs binary search, so it assumes that your list is sorted. Yours isn't sorted.

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) says (emphasis added):

> This module provides support for **maintaining** a list in sorted order

You have to sort your list before you can do anything with `bisect`.

Comment: Okay - so how would I find the index of the first time data reaches threshold?

Comment: @Blochio either sort your list, or do a linear search

Comment: @Blochio: I'm not sure what you think `bisect` does or why you're using it here.  If you have a question about how to do something (like how to find the first occurrence of a given value in a list), then ask that question directly instead of asking about `bisect`.